# Configure Eclipse to pre-bundle App Engine classes into a single JAR for faster warm-up

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, deployment, jar

After some discussion with a colleague from another company that also uses App Engine, he told me that he managed to cut down his app warm up time from ~15 seconds to ~5 seconds using the following steps:

> 1. Configure Eclipse to bundle classes produced during compilation into a single JAR file.
> 2. Configure Eclipse to upload this single JAR file instead of hundreds (or thousands) of separate Java classes during App Engine deployment.

He argues that during instance warm up, since the instance need to load only a single bundled JAR file instead of thousands of separate classes, the warm up would be significantly faster. Any thoughts or opinions about this?

I would definitely like to try it by myself, but I don't have enough Eclipse-mojo to know how to configure such steps. Does anyone know how to configure Eclipse or the Google Plugin for Eclipse to do the steps outlined above? (And have the deployed apps successfully runs in App Engine, of course)

Thank You,

Comment: Why don't you send your colleague a link to this page so he can explain exactly what he did? (:

Comment: @Marcelo: That's one good option, I'll also do that :)

Comment: I'm sure he told you about `jar`, not `war`

Comment: I've heard that this is significantly faster for large applications. I saw someone decrease their spin-up time by several seconds. It seems that Google's file system is relatively slow and that loading a single, compressed JAR is quite a lot quicker than loading small files or uncompressed data. Uncompressing is a relatively cheap operation.

Comment: Akamai, one of the leading content distribution networks, serves large quantities of static files much more efficiently by pulling them out of indexed ZIP files than my storing them individually.  Since a WAR and a JAR are both just specific types of ZIP files, I can definitely imagine Google's AppEngine would likewise see a lot of speedup.  I think it has to do with the cost of locating a file in a distributed file system (high) versus reading the file once you've found it (low), particularly when you can cram several files into one block/disk read/buffer size/memory page/whatever.

Comment: The eclipse plugin merely does a "appcfg.sh update /path/to/wardir".
And when I try to do the same with a war file 
"appcfg.sh update /path/to/filename.war" I get the message 

"appcfg only accepts webapp directories, not war files". And this is with app engine "Release: 1.6.3"

Comment: @IgorArtamonov: Yes, indeed, thanks for the catch. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in an [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038763/2099217), the App Engine SDK supports packaging `WEB-INF/classes` into a jar file, which will end up in `WEB-INF/lib/_ah_webinf_classes-0000.jar`. You can activate this

1. using the appcfg tool with the option `--enable_jar_classes`.
2. using the Google Plugin for Eclipse by configuring the properties of either your WAR or EAR project: Project properties > Google App Engine > Deployment > "Package WEB-INF/classes as a jar"

For me, on App Engine 1.9.4, this resulted in only a minor improvement in instance spin-up (about 5-10 %, if any).

---

Note that this will package **all** files in WEB-INF/classes (not only .class ones). Following the change, I got an error message during instantiation about not being able to read the logging.properties file anymore; probably because the new jar file hasn't been read at that time:

`Unable to read the java.util.logging configuration file, WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties`

As a workaround, I changed the path in appengine-web.xml to `WEB-INF/logging.properties` and configured the maven-war-plugin to copy the file to that location:

```
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>lib</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- Workaround: During GAE deployment, all files in WEB-INF/classes will be packaged into WEB-INF/lib/_ah_webinf_classes-0000.jar, 
                            which prevents the logging.properties referenced in appengine-web.xml from being read. -->
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>logging.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
```

Comment: I don't see any Deployment menu in Google App engine menu. So right click -> Properties -> Google -> App Engine-> ??? . Where exactly is this menu. May be they have removed this , and are doing this automatically ?

Answer (score 4):

What we did in Eclipse was:

- In Project Properties > Java Build Path (Source tab) change output folder from war/WEB-INF/classes to something else, e.g. bin (I believe Eclipse complained about this once)
- In Project Properties > Builders add a new builder (I used type "program builder" and pointed it to the jar executable in my JDK, but as others mentioned an Ant builder would work too). Obviously you should configure this builder to take its input from wherever you decided to write your class files to, and output to something like war/WEB-INF/lib/myclasses.jar

You can configure the jar builder to execute automatically as class files change (which in turn are usually automatically recompiled as your source files change).

There are some downsides, though. For some reason the google eclipse plugin gets confused by your changing the output directory of the java compiler. This means you will have to manually point to the war directory when deploying, and I believe you'll have to manually copy some GAE jars into the war/WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how (or if) you can integrate it into eclipse, but it's fairly trivial to do with **ant**:

```
<import file="${appengine.sdk.dir}/config/user/ant-macros.xml" />

<target name="deploy">
    <delete dir="${staging.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${staging.dir}" />

    <copy todir="${staging.dir}">
        <fileset dir="war">
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/classes/**" />
            <exclude name="WEB-INF/appengine-generated/**" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="${staging.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" />

    <appcfg action="update" war="${staging.dir}" />
</target>
```

I will add that I did not experience a 3X reduction in app startup time.  I posted some experimental numbers in this thread:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/dStBW4wIemY/K69f9ufDiN0J

What I found is that instead of varying wildly from 20-45s, it made my app consistently load in 20s.  It has not subsequently remained this consistent, but I still jar my classes as a standard part of deployment now.

Answer (score 3):

One way this can be achieved if by doing the deployment through Ant, as described in: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant

Next you can modify the ant build.xml file to call the ant  command for building the jar file. Just before the actual deployment you can either delete or move the compiled artifacts away. The build jar-file should be placed in the WAR/WEB-INF/lib folder.

Drawback of this solution is that you have to deploy through the build.xml, i.s.o. through the appengine eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of version 1.7.4:

> You can now package all the WEB-INF/classes/* classes into jar files. This can be done via the new
>
> `--enable_jar_classes` option in the [appcfg](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Uploading_the_App) tools. By default, this option is not set.

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes

Comment: excellent ! With this simple option I could reduce the loading time. Now a cold start request takes about 8.5 sec, before it was always over 15 sec. Note : this module loads about 65 classes. It really seems that the disk i/o latency is the bottleneck.

Comment: Richard, do you know how to integrate this option in eclipse's config so that a deploy through the eclipse plug-in will do it ? I'm not saying it's boring to create a simple script with the right appcfg command in it, but it's simpler to click on a shortcut rather than opening a console to start the script / enter the command... Thank a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to have a separate project that you write all the code in as well as store any other dependencies. When you're ready to deploy, Eclipse's export to runnable JAR file can repack all the dependencies and your classes into a single JAR file, which you would then use as your one dependency in your deployable Google App Engine project which would basically consist of any config files in the WEB-INF folder as well as other static resources + the one big JAR file.

Alternatively to the eclipse export, you can set that up as a Maven or Ant build which can also do the repacking.

Comment: The bounty is about to expire, but I could start a new one if the answer is satisfactory. Say project A is where the meat of my app is located, and project B is the deployable skeleton project with config files and static resources. Is it possible to automate project A jar export to project B's WEB-INF/lib folder every time project B is deployed to GAE?

Comment: Not easily. The google GAE plugin for eclipse does not have any hooks or triggers that will let you run commands before uploading. However, you could do it by writing a shell (or ant or maven) script that builds project A and exports the jar into project B then runs the GAE deployment command line script ("appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh update war"). You could add that into Eclipse as a launch configuration via run->external tools->external tools configuration

Answer (score 0):

> He argues that during instance warm up, since the instance need to load only a 
>   single bundled WAR file instead of thousands of separate classes, the warm up 
>   would be significantly faster. Any thoughts or opinions about this?

I doubt it. WAR is just a ZIP file, which gets unpacked when it's deployed on the server. So there is an additional step, meaning the process can be equally fast (if unpacked when uploaded) or slower (if unpacked when instance is spun up).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tend to think the unpacking is done when the instance is spinning up. The speed up could be due to faster disk I/O when loading a single file compared to loading thousands of separate files. Compared to zip unpacking, disk I/O would be several magnitudes slower, so the overall savings could be greater than the additional overhead. I'll edit the question with some benchmark comparisons once someone come up with a working configuration.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but this really isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @jeffrey_t_b, it's my own fault, I asked for opinions on my question, though I originally hoped the opinions would be voiced in comments instead of answers. =/ But you are right, my question is not the one that tried to be addressed in this answer. :)

Comment: The OP is probably confused about packaging all class files as a single jar, not packaging the entire project as a war file.  The GAE deploy tool does not work with war files, although it can certainly upload jar files in the WEB-INF/lib dir.

Comment: I think we should ask the ones that know how appengine's classloader's implementation is done. So, google guys, do have hints for us ?