# How can I JAR up my classes before uploading to Google App Engine

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, google-app-engine, jar

I have read that JARing up Java classes before uploading them to App Engine improves performance. Can anyone explain how that is done? Can that be achieved from within Eclipse?

Comment: You can vote for this being done automatically: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use Ant to make the jar

```
<property name="staging.dir" value="war"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${staging.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>

<target name="jarClasses">
    <delete file="${staging.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar" />
    <echo> ${staging.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar DELETED </echo>
    <jar destfile="${staging.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" />
    <echo> ${staging.dir}/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar JARRED </echo>
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <echo> ${classes.dir} DELETED </echo>
</target>
```

My layout is like:

```
/war
/build.xml
```

Alternatively you can use an Ant task to deploy

[Configure Eclipse to pre-bundle App Engine classes into a single JAR for faster warm-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397101/configure-eclipse-to-pre-bundle-app-engine-classes-into-a-single-jar-for-faster)

I haven't done it that way as I'm not sure how to handle the passphrase authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse).

It assembles all components required to build WAR files. Deployment must be done manually though.

Comment: Would be nice if the GAE/J plugin did that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about, but you can make a JAR out of an eclipse project by right-clicking the project, then choosing Export -> Java -> Jar file.
Make sure to choose the entry class/main class, or it won't work!